# Flutter : Creating generic interactive Cards to use in listView.builder

Tags: flutter

I created a class for "InteractiveCards" : it is a generic class to create card to display various types of lists through a list view builder. These interactive cards have a "menu button" (to see more) : when we hit this button, it displays further elements (buttons, other lists etc...). I use a boolean for this : _menuOpen is true when user clicks on the three dots, it is false, when user clicks again and the card closes.   Here is a visual of the interactive card :

[image]

For the different buttons : I use "as void Function()?" and then when we use the card, I write the code for this functionality.

```
ElevatedButton(
                              child: Text(
                                widget.bouton1!,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: uD.smallFont,
                                ),
                              ),
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                minimumSize: Size(20, 35),
                                primary: Colors.green[900],
                                onPrimary: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onPressed:
                                  widget.onTapBouton1 as void Function()?,
                            ),
```

Here is the problem : For the button that I named "SUPPRIMER" (Delete) : user clicks on DELETE : it deletes the element from the list, but the particular element in the list is removed : and the thing is that the MENU of the next item is opened automatically. Same thing with "MODIFIER NOM" : I change the name of the item, it is sorted automatically. So when this is done : the items of the lists are no longer in the same order. The _menuOpen which was set to true on the card where the user was doing the changes is now open on another card...

Any idea how I could improve this ?
Meaning : if a menu is open on a certain card : it should stay open even if order of the list is changed... and when the element is removed, it shouldn't open the menu of the card next in line...

Would there be a way to set "_menuOpen" to false when clicking some of the buttons ? The thing is I can't manage to couple "a setState" with " widget.onTapBouton1 as void Function()?"....

Comment: A bit more code would be helpful to see how the elements, lists etc. are bound to a state for example. 
The Problem could be a missing widget key (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html) or missing state updates. It's hard to tell without more code.

Comment: Inside the "interactive card" widget : I use SetState. it is a stateful widget. I use SetState() and _menuOpen to true or false to open and shut the menu (You can see what it does on the visual when we hit the three vertical dots). I edited the end of my question.

Comment: I am not using any widget keys. .I don't really understand what they are for and how to use them.